# how to test open_basedir setting and make sure it is working correctly

Tags: php, linux, fastcgi, whm, open-basedir

I have a VPS using FastCGI (WHM/cPanel). As I understand it, open_basedir must be set using a php.ini file in each user's /home/ directory (E.g.: setting it globally in apache config file will not work).

I want to use open_basedir for improved security, as I recently had a hack that involved traversing through different user's directories

I have added this value to a home directory's php.ini file:
open_basedir = /home/USERNAME/public_html:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp

What I want to know is, is there a way to test that this is functioning properly? Presumably I would want to try and execute a .php file in another user's directory from within that first user...however I don't know of a good way to test this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try listing the contents of a different user's public_html folder:

```
<?php
print_r(shell_exec('ls /home/$anotheruser/public_html/'));
?>
```

If open_basedir is configured properly, you will see a directory listing for that folder.